# How can I implement a RESTful API in Perl?

Tags: perl, rest

I'm trying to implement a RESTful API in Perl. My current idea is to simply parse the path_info with a regex then dispatch the request to the appropriate subroutine which will then spit out the JSON, XML or even XHTML for the requested resource.

For example to retrieve info about user 1234 the RESTful client should find it at:

**http://example.com/model.pl/users/1234**

Below is the skeleton code of my first attempt at implementing a RESTful API:

**model.pl** :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();

print $q->header('text/html');

my $restfuluri  = $q->path_info;

if      ($restfuluri =~ /^\/(questions)\/([1-9]+$)/) { questions($1, $2); }
elsif   ($restfuluri =~ /^\/(users)\/([1-9]+$)/)     { users($1, $2); }


sub questions
{
      my $object = shift;
      my $value  = shift;

      #This is a stub, spits out JSON or XML when implemented.
      print $q->p("GET question : $object -> $value");
}

sub users
{
      my $object = shift;
      my $value  = shift;

      #This is a stub, spits out JSON or XML when implemented.
      print $q->p("GET user: $object -> $value");
}
```

Before I proceed any further, I would like to hear from experienced Perl hackers whether I got the basic idea right and if there are any serious shortcomings with this approach in terms of performance.

I can imagine, after a while, the if/else block would grow really large.

Looking forward to hear your views to make this code better.

Comment: Can I suggest that if you objective is build a RESTful API that you spend some more time learning about REST.  RESTful interfaces are not about using pretty URLs to deliver XML and JSCON.

Comment: Check other questions on StackOverflow that explain REST in detail.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I know what is REST and I'm aware of the uses and abuses of REST. I just need a quick and dirty way of providing a RESTful API for a legacy app. It has a well developed data layer, all I need to do is to allow people to access the data formatted as JSON or XML using pretty URIs. I maintain stuff that has to be more reliable than sexy. I've taken the intiative to read the RESTful Web services O'Reilly book and most of Brian's book before even asking. I think this is a legit question. Furthermore, most of the discussions talk about Ruby. Thanks.

Comment: @Darrel Miiler, unfortunately, I just need to do exactly just that, and no more: using pretty URLs to deliver XML and JSON. Thanks. ;-)

Comment: @GeneQ, pretty URIs are fine, RPC is fine, just do not call it REST when it's not, please. You're also mistaken about reliability - the point of REST is to avoid brittle coupling in the URI space, so it's unfair to say you need something "more reliable than sexy." I haven't read those books - if you're interested, I suggest you read Fielding's dissertation for the authoritative source.

Comment: @GeneQ My mistake.  It is hard to tell how much someone does or does not know about REST.  Just out of curiosity, why do you need the API to be RESTful. Would not a simple XML data payload over Http be sufficient?  I assume you are planning to have the client know about the url structure in advance, and know that certain infosets of XML are going to come from certain endpoints, so what benefits does a "RESTful" api provide you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use something like CGI::Application::Dispatch, it lets me build a dispatch table with variables and REST methods, and lets you use CGI and CGI::Application modules from CPAN. E.g.:

```
table => [
'/questions/:id[get]'    => { rm => 'get_question' },
'/users/:id[get]'        => { rm => 'get_user' }, # OR
':app/:id[post]'         => { rm => 'update' }, # where :app is your cgi application module
':app/:id[delete]'       => { rm => 'delete' },
],
```

(or you can use auto_rest or auto_rest_lc)

you can use a separate CGI::Application class for each type of thing (or just use classes in your cgi-app controller class methods).

CGI::Application also comes with plugins for outputting XML, JSON or text generated from templates.

cgi-app (and c::a::d) are are CGI applications and can be used with (little or) no change under CGI, FastCGI or mod_perl.  C::A::D is also a mod_perl PerlHandler by default too.

Answer (score 22):

For lightweight REST APIs I would look at Mojolicious. The request routing is really straightforward and the inbuilt JSON renderer and user agent make development of simple REST APIs very straightforward in my experience.

If your app is going to be relatively small then [Mojo::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) may suit your requirements. For example you may be able to do something like this:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/questions/(:question_id)' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $result = {};
    # do stuff with $result based on $self->stash('question_id')
    return $self->render_json($result)
}

app->start;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd build the application using [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) and [Catalyst::Controller::REST](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Action-REST-0.74/lib/Catalyst/Controller/REST.pm)

Comment: Thanks. But I'll pass. Nothing against Catalyst, this is jsut ot provide an RESTful interface to a (very) legacy app. Quick & Dirty stuff. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the already implemented module [Apache2::REST](http://search.cpan.org/~jeteve/Apache2-REST-0.07/lib/Apache2/REST.pm) ?
It is all there.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution:

```
 use CGI;

 my $page  = new CGI;

 if( $ENV{ 'REQUEST_METHOD' } eq 'GET' ){

    my $data = <<json;
    {
    "isbn" : "123456",
    "title" : "Programming Perl",
    "author" : "L. Wall"
     }
 json

     print $page->header('application/json');

     print $data;
 }
```

Comment: Because the here-document in your example does not work due to spacing, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a long time since this question has been asked, but I would like to provide some updated information.

There is a very useful module called [Net::API::REST](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::API::REST) using Apache2 mod_perl behind.

You just need to set up Apache, and create your own module inheriting from [Net::API::REST](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::API::REST) and create an `init` method in which you define your endpoints map, such as:

```
sub init
{
    my $self = shift( @_ );
    $self->{routes} =
    {
    # e.g. your API version 1
    1 =>
        {
        'favicon.ico' => $self->curry::noop,
        auth =>
            {
            google =>
                {
                _handler => $self->curry::oauth_google,
                callback => $self->curry::oauth_google(callback => 1),
                },
            linkedin =>
                {
                _handler => $self->curry::oauth_linkedin,
                callback => $self->curry::oauth_linkedin(callback => 1),
                },
            },
        },
        stripe => $self->curry::stripe,
    };
    $self->{api_version} = 1;
    $self->{supported_api_versions} = [qw( 1 )];
    $self->{default_methods} = [qw( GET POST )];
    $self->{supported_methods} = [qw( DELETE GET HEAD OPTIONS POST PUT )];
    $self->{supported_languages} = [qw( en-GB en fr-FR fr ja-JP )];
    $self->SUPER::init( @_ );
    return( $self );
}
```

And when someone access one of your endpoint, your corresponding method gets called in the context of a powerful environment to use to reply to the request. Check the module metacpan page for more information.

Answer (score -1):

The Simple Solution - with a variable tweak on `$data` using `qq~~;` Keeps all code lined up.

```
 use CGI;

 my $page  = new CGI;

 if( $ENV{ 'REQUEST_METHOD' } eq 'GET' ){

    my $data = qq~
        {
            "isbn" : "123456",
            "title" : "Programming Perl",
            "author" : "L. Wall"
        }
    ~;

     print $page->header('application/json');

     print $data;
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you use apache mod_rewrite?

Redirect http://mysite.com/model.pl/users/1234 --> http://mysite.com/users.pl

Redirect http://mysite.com/model.pl/q/5678 --> http://mysite.com/questions.pl

Comment: If you're using apache and mod_rewrite, why even include the .pl?  Also you are losing the ID.  You can rewrite the URL with mod_rewrite or just create a mod_perl handler and use it to handle /dir/whatever.  CGI::Application::Dispatch is a mod_perl handler, and can do rest.